# How to emit/access workflow state to view

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

I am currently practicing the use of Workflow Foundation 4, and I have met a problem. I have created a workflow with a loop in it. The workflow ends, when a specific requirement is met. I have no problems getting the results, but what I want to do, is to be able to monitor the state of the workflow, while it is running, and showing it on a basic UI. Imagine it like this:

```
while(x>0)
{
  delay for 2 seconds
  assign x=x-1
}
```

What I want to do is to be able to show the x value on a UI, without having to write display logic into the workflow, so it remains reuseable. (Basically using the workflow as a model)

I have tried to write a `NativeActivity`, to create a bookmark, and somehow access the variables of the workflow in the Idle event handler, but I was unsuccesful doing so.

Note: Of course the actual workflow is not a simple loop counting, but it is unneccessary, to go into details.

EDIT:
I have tried going on with creating a workflow extension, with not much luck. Here is what I did:

public class Watcher : IWorkflowInstanceExtension
    {
        private WorkflowInstanceProxy instanceproxy;

```
    public IEnumerable<object> GetAdditionalExtensions()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void SetInstance(WorkflowInstanceProxy instance)
    {
        instanceproxy = instance;
    }

    public Dictionary<string, int> GetData()
    {
        ???
    }

}
```

So the idea was to return a dictionary of the values I am interested in. The problem is, the WorkflowInstanceProxy class doesn't seems to have anything I can use to extract workflow variables, or anything for that matter.

Comment: In WF4 you've the concept of [Tracking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee513992%28VS.100%29.aspx) where you add your tracking participant as an extension and it outputs whatever you want, maybe to a database where you keep the state of each workflow.

Comment: I'd just create an extension.  http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/wfext/

Comment: Jota: The problem with tracking is it writes to the Windows event logs. I do not want that.
Will: "Just creating an extension" is not very helpful. The only example I found utilises the only two methods I have found, wich is "BeginResumeBookmark", and "EndResumeBookmark". Could you be more specific?

Comment: @Robert TrackingParticipant can write to whatever place you want. As a matter of fact [TrackingParticipant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.tracking.trackingparticipant.aspx) is an abstract class and you just implement the write logic the way you want. You then publish it to workflow as an extension. Check [this samples](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21459) in particular the *WF\Basic\Tracking* folder.